# Use IIS URL Rewrite module to point to a subdomain

Tags: iis, rewrite

My web page is located at `maxpavlov.com/interesting/fileupload/`

Can I use URL Rewrite module in IIS to have a user address bar show `file.maxpavlov.com` every time he visits the aforementioned url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL Rewrite can't change the URL displayed in the address bar, per se.  However, if you linked to file.maxpavlov.com (rather than maxpavlov.com/interesting/fileupload/), you could use URL Rewrite to rewrite that request to maxpavlov.com/interesting/fileupload/:

```
<rule name="CustomRule" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="file.maxpavlov.com" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="maxpavlov.com/interesting/fileupload/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: So it is one way around - not the other =) Thanks.

Comment: You could always 302 or 301 redirect maxpavlov.com/interesting/fileupload/ to file.maxpavlov.com and then use URL Redirect to rewrite that to your hidden file area ;-)